Is there an obligation for a Beit Din to explain their psak?
When a Beit Din issues a ruling, are the judges required to provide the reasoning behind their ruling?
Is the ruling valid (meaning, must it be followed) if no explanation was provided? Can the loser claim that the ruling is wrong or invalid on the basis of a missing full ruling?

Judges are required to give the reason behind their ruling upon request. According to the Shulchan Aruch (Choshen Mishpat 14:4), this is the case even if the judge isn't asked explicitly but one of the parties suspects the ruling given isn't right.
According to the Rama (there), the losing party is still required to pay immediately, even before the ruling is written down, and the ruling can be reversed if it turns out to be incorrect. Whether the explanation has to be delivered orally before the payment isn't mentioned, so I'm not sure, but I notice that it's absent from the formula איש פלוני אתה זכאי איש פלוני אתה חייב (Choshen Mishpat 19:1). If the losing party wants to appeal to another court, the document they can request is required to list only the claims of both parties and the ruling, without the reasons (and the loser would, of course, appeal based on the ruling being incorrect, not based on the lack of an explanation).

and the loser would, of course, appeal based on the ruling being incorrect, not based on the lack of an explanation in other words, the new court would/should not consider the previous court's ruling but should examine it fresh given the facts?

וא"צ לכתוב לו הטעמים והראיות רק כותבין להם הטענות והפסק דין (Choshen Mishpat 14:4) seems to suggest that they don't have to provide the reasons...

@Igshost they don’t have to write the reasons on a document, but they have to be able to provide them if prompted.

@lgshost 1. Yes, if you sue someone you're claiming that the money should belong to you by Torah law, and that the first court made a mistake in applying it, so the new court would have to see the case by the same standard, Torah law. 2. As Qwertrl said, the Rama is saying they don't have to provide the reasons in a written document. This is what I wrote in the last sentence of the answer: the document is required to list only the claims of both parties and the ruling, without the reasons.

@ba but the Choshen Mishpat clearly says that they do have to provide the reasons. This is why I'm confused

@lgshost They have to provide the reasons, but not in a written document. They have to provide a written record of the ruling, as proof of which party won, or to allow the case to be retried in a superior court, but don't have to give the reasons, because all the courts are seeing the case based on the same Torah, not by fiat of the previous court. But if the losing party wants to know why he lost (or even just suspects the judges of impartiality, according to this opinion), the judges do have to tell him the reason why he lost, but they aren't required to write it down.
